# setTimeOut in Angular to cause a delay in returning data

Tags: javascript, angular

```
getCustomersFromAPICall(): CustomerModel[] {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        return this.dataFromAPICall = [
            {
                firstName: 'Nintendo',
                lastName: 'Switch',
                caseID: 123,
                employeeNumber: 1234,
                photo: 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/90/27/39/360_F_290273933_ukYZjDv8nqgpOBcBUo5CQyFcxAzYlZRW.jpg',
                displayCaseCode: '15',
                reasonName: '1C',
                frequencyType: FrequencyType.Intermittent,
                emailAddress: 'NJ',
                networkID: 'ABC',
                caseState: CaseState.Open,
                requestDate: new Date('12/12/2012'),
                startDate: new Date('12/01/1990'),
                endDate: new Date('12/01/2000'),
                lastUpdated: new Date('1/1/1991')
            },
            {
                firstName: 'Nintendo',
                lastName: 'Switch',
                caseID: 124,
                employeeNumber: 1234,
                photo: 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/90/27/39/360_F_290273933_ukYZjDv8nqgpOBcBUo5CQyFcxAzYlZRW.jpg',
                displayCaseCode: '15',
                reasonName: '1C',
                frequencyType: FrequencyType.Continuous,
                emailAddress: 'NJ',
                networkID: 'ABC',
                caseState: CaseState.Closed,
                requestDate: new Date('12/12/2012'),
                startDate: new Date('12/01/1990'),
                endDate: new Date('12/01/2000'),
                lastUpdated: new Date('1/1/1991')
            },
            {
                firstName: 'Nintendo',
                lastName: 'Switch',
                caseID: 125,
                employeeNumber: 1234,
                photo: 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/90/27/39/360_F_290273933_ukYZjDv8nqgpOBcBUo5CQyFcxAzYlZRW.jpg',
                displayCaseCode: '15',
                reasonName: '1C',
                frequencyType: FrequencyType.Intermittent,
                emailAddress: 'NJ',
                networkID: 'ABC',
                caseState: CaseState.Closed,
                requestDate: new Date('12/12/2012'),
                startDate: new Date('12/01/1990'),
                endDate: new Date('12/01/2000'),
                lastUpdated: new Date('1/1/1991')
            },
            {
                firstName: 'Storm',
                lastName: 'Kevin',
                caseID: 123,
                employeeNumber: 1239,
                photo: 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/90/27/39/360_F_290273933_ukYZjDv8nqgpOBcBUo5CQyFcxAzYlZRW.jpg',
                displayCaseCode: '15',
                reasonName: '1C',
                frequencyType: FrequencyType.Intermittent,
                emailAddress: 'NJ',
                networkID: 'ABC',
                caseState: CaseState.Open,
                requestDate: new Date('12/12/2012'),
                startDate: new Date('12/01/1990'),
                endDate: new Date('12/01/2000'),
                lastUpdated: new Date('1/1/1991')
            },
            {
                firstName: 'Scott',
                lastName: 'Summer',
                caseID: 124,
                employeeNumber: 1235,
                photo: 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/90/27/39/360_F_290273933_ukYZjDv8nqgpOBcBUo5CQyFcxAzYlZRW.jpg',
                displayCaseCode: '15',
                reasonName: '1C',
                frequencyType: FrequencyType.Continuous,
                emailAddress: 'NJ',
                networkID: 'ABC',
                caseState: CaseState.Closed,
                requestDate: new Date('12/12/2012'),
                startDate: new Date('12/01/2000'),
                endDate: new Date('12/01/2001'),
                lastUpdated: new Date('1/1/2005')
            },
            {
                firstName: 'Victor',
                lastName: 'Von Doom',
                caseID: 125,
                employeeNumber: 1236,
                photo: 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/90/27/39/360_F_290273933_ukYZjDv8nqgpOBcBUo5CQyFcxAzYlZRW.jpg',
                displayCaseCode: '15',
                reasonName: '1C',
                frequencyType: FrequencyType.Intermittent,
                emailAddress: 'NJ',
                networkID: 'ABC',
                caseState: CaseState.Open,
                requestDate: new Date('12/12/2012'),
                startDate: new Date('12/01/2010'),
                endDate: new Date('12/01/2005'),
                lastUpdated: new Date('1/1/2009')
            },
            {
                firstName: 'Bruce',
                lastName: 'Banner',
                caseID: 126,
                employeeNumber: 1237,
                photo: 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/90/27/39/360_F_290273933_ukYZjDv8nqgpOBcBUo5CQyFcxAzYlZRW.jpg',
                displayCaseCode: '15',
                reasonName: '1C',
                frequencyType: FrequencyType.Continuous,
                emailAddress: 'NJ',
                networkID: 'ABC',
                caseState: CaseState.Open,
                requestDate: new Date('12/12/2012'),
                startDate: new Date('05/01/1990'),
                endDate: new Date('01/01/1000'),
                lastUpdated: new Date('1/1/2021')
            },
            {
                firstName: 'Peter',
                lastName: 'Parker',
                caseID: 127,
                employeeNumber: 1238,
                photo: 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/90/27/39/360_F_290273933_ukYZjDv8nqgpOBcBUo5CQyFcxAzYlZRW.jpg',
                displayCaseCode: '15',
                reasonName: '1C',
                frequencyType: FrequencyType.Continuous,
                emailAddress: 'NJ',
                networkID: 'ABC',
                caseState: CaseState.Closed,
                requestDate: new Date('12/12/2012'),
                startDate: new Date('08/01/2015'),
                endDate: new Date('01/01/1000'),
                lastUpdated: new Date('10/1/2022')
            }
        ];
    }, 2000);
    return this.dataFromAPICall;
}
```

With this code, i do not seem to be getting the desired results

```
 findEmployee() {
    //debugger;
    this.searchEmployeeList = this.getCustomersFromAPICall();
```

if I remove the setTimeout, it works fine but I wanted to test the UI if the network was slow by adding a setTimeout()

Comment: If you want to "test the UI if the network was slow", you can do this via Chrome's inspector by going to the Network tab and changing 'No throttling' to something slower like Slow 3G.

But for the function you provided, looks like you have a return *outside* of the setTimeout, this is probably why the function returns instantly.

Comment: that won't work because there is NO network call. It's all being managed in the app.
I want to use setTimeout to introduce a delay when the data is returned

Comment: return of(this.dataFromAPICall).pipe(delay(500));

Comment: @peinearydevelopment: You should post this as an answer. Your suggestion is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

## Your code is correctly returning an empty value

It would be easier for you if you replaced the lengthy object with a smaller one, and trimmed your variable/function names. You would instantly recognise that this is incorrect:

```
getCustomers(){

    setTimeout(()={
        return this.data = [{ test: 1 }]
    })
    return this.data
}
```

Your function sets up a timeout, but *immediately* returns the *current* value of `this.data`. That is why you are getting nothing back - you are getting the value of `this.data` before you have added the elements to it.

## What you probably want is an asynchronous function

Look into promises: how to create them and how to return them.

See if you can design an asynchronous function: this can return a promise, rather than an actual value. The promise can later resolve into the actual value. For example, this could be after a delay controlled by setTimeout.

Comment: I did as you demonstrated. how do I make the code inside findEmployee() to wait for the results? Because now TypeScript is saying Propertly filter does not exist on void.

Comment: @software is fun: I'd rather not use `setTimeout`. Instead I'd follow the advice that peinearydevelopment gave you in the comments below your question and use `delay()` instead.

Comment: @softwareisfun, please provide a piece of code that can actually be executed live in Stack Overflow, using the `<>` symbol above your text entry box. Keep it as short as possible, yet demonstrating the bug. Otherwise you will end up in a situation like this, writing about `filter`, when the code you present does not include an attempt to call `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Promises...

```
 const customerFixture: CustomerModel[] = {
       ...
       employeeNumber: 1234,
       endDate: new Date('12/01/2000'),
       lastUpdated: new Date('1/1/1991'),
       ...
}

getCustomersFromAPICall(): Promise<CustomerModel[]> {
   // Here you return a promise that be resolve in 2 seconds (2000 in milliseconds) with customers
   return new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve(customerFixture), 2000),
    );;
}
```

```
async findEmployee() {
    //You should wait the promise to be solved using "await" word before the method call. Also to make this work you have to add "async" word before this method name.
    this.searchEmployeeList = await this.getCustomersFromAPICall();
    // try to log it
    console.log(this.searchEmployeeList)
```

Another option if you dont want to use async/await would be

```
findEmployee() {
    //In this case you dont block the thread waiting the two seconds to be solved
    this.getCustomersFromAPICall().then(customers => {
      this.searchEmployeeList = customers;
      console.log(this.searchEmployeeList)
    })
    // try to log it
```

Comment: the result (this.searchEmployeeList) is of type Promise<CustomerModel[]> How can i use methods like .forEach and .filter? These don't exist for Promises. I used async/await